# New to Windows Azure Preview

Tags: azure, web, ftp, alias, preview

3 questions about Windows Azure Website Preview service (placing my website into cloud):
1. A little embarrassing, but I can't find my FTP credential. I tried my website setup credential as well as the data source string. Both are not applicable. So where is it?
2. I also need database access too, but can't seem to find the entry URL for that as well. Any inputs are appreciated.
3. Finally, I bought my own domain. How can I do an alias (maybe from Apache or IIS, not sure though) so that users only see example.com instead of example.azurewebsites.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You'll find the FTP credentials in the publish profile. In the Windows Azure portal, simply open the dashboard of that site and choose **Download publish profile**. Open that file with any text editor and you'll see the FTP credentials.
2. If you want to use a database, go to the dashboard of that site and choose to add a linked resource. There you'll be able to add an SQL Database. Once you've done that you'll see the connection string under **Quick Glance > View connection strings**
3. Using your own domain with Windows Azure Web Sites is [only possible with reserved instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027635/can-i-point-my-domain-name-to-an-azure-web-site/11027704#11027704) with a CNAME.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy your application to Windows Azure Websites over FTP, you can take a look at [my blog here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/19/windows-azure-website-uploading-downloading-files-over-ftp-and-collecting-diagnostics-logs.aspx) which explains most of the info related to FTP deployment.

As Sandrino explained you can look at View Connections Settings at Quick Glance, also if you look at following sections [in the article](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-configure-websites/) here you will get more on this regard:

1. How to: Configure a website to use a SQL database
2. How to: Configure a website to use a MySQL database

Rest is already answered for you.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got 1 and 3. But for number 2, I'm still having problem. I can see the mySQLDBConnectionString in the publish profile, but I can't connect to the address it provided (us-cdbr-azure-east-a.cloudapp.net). I need to reimport the database. Is it inaccessible or is it a network problem?

Angela